# React Native DropDownPicker scroll not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I have a component that contains `DropDownPicker` from `react-native-dropdown-picker` package. When `DropDownPicker` is visible I'm unable to scroll to see all items in the list.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import allColors from '../config/colors';
import ThemeContext from '../theme/context';

const FilterItem = ({
  label,
  placeholder,
  values,
  triggerClose,
  setTriggerClose,
  filterObject,
  setFilterObject,
  keyName,
}) => {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const colors = allColors[theme];

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(filterObject[keyName]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(values);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(false);
  }, [triggerClose]);

  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.container,
        {
          minHeight: open
            ? values.length >= 3
              ? 180
              : 90 + 25 * values.length
            : 0,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={[styles.label, { color: colors.secondary }]}>{label}</Text>
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        value={value}
        items={items}
        setOpen={(value) => {
          if (value) setTriggerClose(!triggerClose);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setOpen(value);
          }, 100);
        }}
        setValue={(value) => {
          setValue(value);
          setFilterObject({ ...filterObject, [keyName]: value() });
        }}
        setItems={setItems}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        ArrowDownIconComponent={({ style }) => (
          <FontAwesome5
            style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}
            name='caret-down'
            size={18}
            color='#AAAAAA'
          />
        )}
        ArrowUpIconComponent={({ style }) => (
          <FontAwesome5
            style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}
            name='caret-up'
            size={18}
            color='#AAAAAA'
          />
        )}
        placeholderStyle={{
          fontFamily: 'barlow',
          color: '#AAAAAA',
          fontSize: 14,
        }}
        style={{
          borderWidth: 0,
          shadowColor: 'black',
          shadowOpacity: 0.3,
          shadowRadius: 2,
          shadowOffset: {
            height: 1,
            width: 0,
          },
          elevation: 2,
          minHeight: 40,
          fontFamily: 'barlow',
          backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? colors.background3 : '#2A1442',
        }}
        itemStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        }}
        maxHeight={values.length >= 3 ? 120 : values.length * 40}
        dropDownContainerStyle={{
          borderWidth: 0.3,
          borderColor: colors.darkGray,
          backgroundColor: theme === 'light' ? colors.background3 : '#2A1442',
        }}
        textStyle={{
          fontFamily: 'barlow',
          color: colors.secondary,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FilterItem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    width: '100%',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  label: {
    fontFamily: 'barlowSemiBold',
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```